# Why the button_tag with extra parameters getting an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, syntax-error, form-helpers

I have a form and a button:

```
= button_tag( "&times;" , type: "button", html: {class: "close", aria-hidden: "true"},  data: {dismiss: "alert"} )
```

it is converted to rails from the twitter bootstrap [ http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts ]:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

But the rails variant getting an error:

```
SyntaxError in Search#get_search
Showing /.../app/views/search/new.html.slim where line #58 raised:

/.../app/views/search/new.html.slim:58: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...: {class: "close", aria-hidden: true},  data: {dismiss: "ale...
...                               ^
/.../app/views/search/new.html.slim:58: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
... {dismiss: "alert"} )))).to_s)); 
...                               ^
```

Something with `aria-hidden: "true"` or `dismiss: "alert"` is wrong

Why is it so? I used different variants which complains to [ http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag ]:

```
button_tag(content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is not allowed:

```
aria-hidden: "true"
```

Replace it with:

```
:"aria-hidden" => "true"
```

or

```
"aria-hidden" => "true"
```

or

```
aria: { hidden: true }
```

Comment: I changed to `= button_tag( "&times;" , type: "button", html: {class: "close", :"aria-hidden" => "true"},  data: {dismiss: "alert"})` and now it works, but it looks a bit ugly and strange so. This: `= button_tag( "&times;" , type: "button", html: {class: "close", "aria-hidden": "true"},  data: {dismiss: "alert"})` didn't work.

Comment: why only the "aria-hidden" ? all other attributes work perfectly with `attr_name: value`

Comment: Nothing strange here - dash is a special symbol. It's used as a minus sign/operator.

Comment: but why `"aria-hidden": "true"` doesn't work, only `:"aria-hidden" => "true"`?

Comment: Because Ruby syntax does not allow this :) Sorry, but I won't give You a better answer. Maybe searching on Ruby feature/bug tracker will yield some result. Maybe it's hard to guess for parser what You actually mean with that syntax.